# How to install ImageMagick with Anaconda on windows 64bits?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, imagemagick, anaconda

I downloaded ImageMagick file for Windows 64bits `ImageMagick-7.0.4-4-Q16-x64-dll.exe`  ([Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)) and I installed it.

I am using Anaconda and I get the following error:

```
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py:784: UserWarning: MovieWriter imagemagick unavailable
  warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
```

Does anybody know a channel for Anaconda where there is the ImageMagick package for win64 ?

PS: For example here is a channel called `kalefranz` with the ImageMagick package but for Linux 64bits only (https://anaconda.org/kalefranz/imagemagick)

Comment: `ImageMagick` is indenpendent program which you can install in any place and use without Python. ie `convert *.jpg result.pdf`. Some Python modules uses `ImageMagick` in background but should find it if you put folder with `ImageMagick` in `PATH`.

Comment: I know but I use Python and I tried to save an animation by writing `ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=60)` and I got the error above. I can save an animation with `ffmpeg` and save it as MP4 but now I want to save it as a GIF.

Comment: did you tried without `writer='imagemagick'`

Comment: I have the ImaheMagick folder `C:\ImageMagick` in my Path. I tried what you told me to but the file that I get is a corrupted GIF and I get the following error: `r.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 244, in grab_frame
    'with --verbose-debug.'.format(e, out, err))
IOError: Error saving animation to file (cause: [Errno 22] Invalid argument) Stdout:  StdError: . It may help to re-run with --verbose-debug.`

Comment: BTW: I try (on Linux) `ffmpeg -i video.avi video.gif` and it gives me animated GIF. So maybe `ffmpeg` could save it as `gif` on your computer.

Comment: Yes it seems to be a good idea. I saw that link and I will let you know if it worked: http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

As @furas said the best way to save an animation is to save it as an MP4 file with `ffmpeg` and then to open `cmd.exe` and type: `ffmpeg -i C:\my_path\animation.mp4 C:\my_path\animation.gif`.

From Python we can do:

```
import os
os.system("ffmpeg -i C:\\my_path\\animation.mp4 C:\\my_path\\animation.gif")
# \\ allows to bypass any ascii issue because for example in python "\a" means "\x07" and "\\a" means "\a"
```

Comment: Is there a way to control the quality of the output gif?

Comment: This answer does not answer the question asked in the title. It may have 'solved' the issue behind the question, but it does not answer the question of how to install imagemagick under windows.

Comment: @Joost +1 for that comment, I hate things like that